# Python binary not considering paths in .bashrc when invoked directly

Tags: bash, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have the binary of GUI application (with a set of .so files) running on linux built from wxpython (using pyinstaller). The application calls a number of sub-applications internally using subprocess.Popen(), which needs some environmental PATH variables set.

I have set the paths added in ~/.bashrc.. The application is running fine when invoked from bash shell.

```
./applicationname
```

However, if I open the binary directly (double-clicking), the sub-application invocations fail due to missing path. Since it is working fine when invoked from bash, I tried to create an applicationwrapper.sh with the following, but didn't help.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /local/mnt/applicationpath/
./applicationname
```

Any idea how I could distribute the application so that the users could invoke it by opening it directly rather than through bash shell?

Comment: Post your `subprocess.Popen()` commands. They may shed some light on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered reading the variables from a configuration file, if the environment variables are found not to exist?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason launching the app is not reading the ./bashrc file and the logic seems quite convoluted, although there is a lot of complicated information available on the web.
To get around this problem Edit the /etc/environment file to include the PATH variables that you wish to add.
(Note: Only tested on an Ubuntu machine (actually Mint 17))
You will need to log off or reboot before it takes effect.